# Mapping a char to its value given predefined char/value pairs

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have predefined string/value pairs such as the following:

```
A = 137.05
B = 128.09
C = 131.04
D = 147.06
```

My function receives a string such as string = "BBDADC" and I have to iterate over each character and sum up each correspondent floating-point value. How can I map each character to its predefined value? The following printing loop shows that the mapping doesn't occur naturally, and the printing results in the char being printed rather that the predefined value. Probably because A != 'A'?. Is there a way to do this mapping? As far as I'm concerned, using a dictionary or a list is not necessary. Thanks.

```
for chr in string:
print chr # print gives a chr, therefore sum += chr doesn't make sense
          # float(chr) neither makes much sense nor works
```

Answer (score 3):

Store these string-value pairs in a **dictionary**:

```
weights = {'A': 137.05, 'B': 128.09, 'C': 131.04, 'D': 147.06}
```

and look them up:

```
for chr in peptide:
    sum += weights[chr]
```

You can use dictionaries whenever you have pairs of names and values, or more generally whenever you want to be able to store and look up some information based on a *key*.

Comment: +1 Or, more succintly, `sum(weights[res] for res in 'BBDADC')` or even `sum(map(weights.get, 'BBDADC'))`

Comment: If you need high precision, use integers (13705, 12809, …) for summing up the values, and then, at the end, divide by 100.0.